# Where does LibreOffice store toolbar icons?

Tags: 14.04, icons, libreoffice

Where does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS store LibreOffice icons ? I mean by that the icons used by the GUI of LibreOffice Writer, LibreOffice Calc, LibreOffice Impress...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icons are stored in compressed files in the folder `/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config`

EG

```
2256 -rw-r--r-- 1 2308309 Aug  4 15:01 images_galaxy.zip
 488 -rw-r--r-- 1  496912 Aug  4 15:01 images_sifr.zip
7268 -rw-r--r-- 1 7440250 Aug  4 15:01 images_tango.zip
```

The icons you can see depends on your selected icon theme.

---

The package name of such a theme or style is

```
libreoffice-style-...
```

List the installable or installed styles in your system via

```
$ dpkg -l libreoffice-style* | awk '/libreoffice-style-/ {print $2}'
libreoffice-style-andromeda
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-style-crystal
libreoffice-style-default
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-hicontrast
libreoffice-style-human
libreoffice-style-oxygen
libreoffice-style-sifr
libreoffice-style-tango
```